# how to capture text from Tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter, I have the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Email Sender")

Label(root, text="To").grid(row=0)
text = StringVar()
toText = Entry(root, textvariable=text)
s= text.get()
root.mainloop()
```

My goal is to create a label "To" and an entry, I am trying to capture whatever typed from keyboard in the entry. However, with the above code, I got empty when I print `s`.

So how could I capture the text typed into the entry?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you need to `grid` (or otherwise place) the `toText`  variable, or it won't show up in the interface.

Comment: @abarnert thanks, I removed that part in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* capturing the text typed into the `Entry`—but you're only doing `s = text.get()` once, before the mainloop has even started, at which point the text typed into the `Entry` is whatever the initial value of the `Entry` was, which is the empty string.

What you need to do is add an event handler that runs at the appropriate time—maybe on the root's close event, or each time the `Entry`'s text is edited, or whatever seems right to you—and does the `s = text.get()`. Then, you'll have whatever was in the `Entry` at the time that event was fired.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation. I will try to figure out how to add an event handler to update the entry.

Comment: @taocp: If the place you want to do it is when the root window gets destroyed, you may want to read [Capturing destroy events](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols) first, because it's not particularly obvious that if you intercept the `WM_DESTROY_WINDOW` protocol, you have to call the `destroy` method that the default handler would have called, or the window doesn't get closed.